# How to determine which piece of hardware is at fault?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, vram

I'm trying to determine which piece of hardware is causing my ASUS Q550LF laptop to fail. I don't want to open the laptop, because it's still under the manufacturer's warranty, and might attempt to return it. Various hardware monitoring tools report consistent results that lead me to believe that the problem isn't simply a dislodged memory stick, or something of that nature.

The problem is that previously I was able to play games that were fairly graphics intensive (for a mid-tier laptop) without problem. Suddenly, they began to chug along at 1-10 frames per second. I haven't noticed significant performance drops in other areas. The performance drop was sudden and coincident with a plane flight (but other than the performance problems, I have no reason to suspect physical damage). I've seen several error message about insufficient video memory since these problems started.

I don't seem to be able to generate any consistent error message that would let me pinpoint the source of the problem, and the laptop's GeForce 745M has no diagnostic tools. What is the best way to determine the nature of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to diagnose this without testing components individually, but my first bet would be that it's software related. Bug in the software itself, a driver screwing you over, etc.

Another alternative is the GPU switching. If I'm not entirely mistaken, your laptop has two GPUs: One nVidia set for high-intensity stuff, and an intel set for basic stuff that allows you to save power when needed. Are you sure it's still using the nVidia GPU for gaming? It is possible that using the laptop during the flight (and on battery) switched it to Intel, and for some reason it never switched back. How to switch this varies from laptop to laptop (I have a dedicated button for it on mine).

But if I had to pick something hardware-related, I would suspect a cooling-related issue. Are the fans working any harder than they used to? Are the temperatures for cores and GPU any higher now than before? If so, opening the laptop is the next stop to ensure that the heatsinks are properly and firmly attached, in addition to replacing the cooling paste (Low cabin pressure could have made this dry up somewhat).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just assumed the issue must be hardware-related. I performed a system reset and reinstalled the graphics drivers, which appears to have resolved the issue.